# Update and replace map value

Tags: clojure

I'm sure it's right here in front of me, but I'm missing it. Examine the following:

```
(assoc :position entity
      (add (:position entity) (:velocity entity)))
```

What I want to do is something like this (with a fake function called altermap):

```
(altermap :position entity #((add % (:velocity entity)))
```

What is the suggested method? Is there a built-in function to do #2?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`update-in` is almost exactly like your `altermap` function, except that it takes a vector of keys instead of a single key. So:

```
(update-in entity [:position] #(add % (:velocity entity)))
```

To the best of my knowledge there is no single-key variant of `update-in`, but having to put brackets around the key shouldn't be too cumbersome.

Comment: I agree. I found update-in shortly after writing this. And update-in has the nice ability to modify trees, which will be really helpful in my project.

Comment: Note that the above update-in is intended to be written -by design- with less parens than the above: `(update-in entity [:position] add (:velocity entity))
`